# SELECT MAX of COUNT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i made query to display the count of total number of positive and negative but i need to get or display only the maximum count of either positive or negative.this is my query

```
SELECT count(`sentiment`) as count,`sentiment` FROM `sno_social_listener` WHERE `keyword_id` = 104 group by `sentiment`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` should be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT count(`sentiment`) as count,
       `sentiment` 
FROM `sno_social_listener` 
WHERE `keyword_id` = 104 
GROUP BY `sentiment` 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you've a misplaced tick